# compare two tables in a query taking so long time

Tags: sybase

I have a a query where i compare 350 rows with other tables which are having 50000 rows it takes 5 minutes to give result.Any faster way to retrieve values get earlier.

```
  select lower(rtrim(substring(rt_queue, 3, 6))) + " Ticor - " + convert(varchar(4), sort_grp_id) + " " + rtrim(batch_no) + ".prn" as FILENAME  from tprt_queue where cycle_date  >= (select CYCLE from tb_jpachi_cycle) and batch_no <> 'JOBCTR-' and rt_queue not like '%CN%' and status = 'TINTED' and lower(rtrim(substring(prt_queue, 3, 6))) + " Bicor - " + convert(varchar(4), sort_grp_id) + " " + rtrim(batch_no) + ".prn"  not in (
    select FILENAME  from tb_jpachi_filesprocess ) order by rt_dt
```

This one contains 100000 rows : select FILENAME  from tb_jpachi_filesprocess

Later it will increase day by day.

Here is query plan :

QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 1 (at line 1).

```
STEP 1
    The type of query is EXECUTE.
    Executing a newly cached statement (SSQL_ID = 230588804).
```

QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 1 (at line 0).

```
STEP 1
    The type of query is DECLARE.
```

QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 2 (at line 1).
Optimized using Serial Mode

```
STEP 1
    The type of query is SELECT.

10 operator(s) under root

   |ROOT:EMIT Operator (VA = 10)
   |
   |   |RESTRICT Operator (VA = 9)(0)(0)(0)(0)(9)
   |   |
   |   |   |SEQUENCER Operator (VA = 8) has 2 children.
   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |SCALAR AGGREGATE Operator (VA = 1)
   |   |   |   |  Evaluate Ungrouped ONCE AGGREGATE.
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 0)
   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |   |   |  tb_jpachi_cycle
   |   |   |   |   |  Table Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning at start of table.
   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |SQFILTER Operator (VA = 7) has 2 children.
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |RESTRICT Operator (VA = 3)(0)(0)(0)(6)(0)
   |   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 2)
   |   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |   |   |   |  tprt_queue
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Using Clustered Index.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Index : pk_tprt_queue
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning at index start.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for index leaf pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |  Run subquery 1 (at nesting level 1).
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |  QUERY PLAN FOR SUBQUERY 1 (at nesting level 1 and at line 2).
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   Correlated Subquery.
   |   |   |   |   Subquery under an IN predicate.
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |SCALAR AGGREGATE Operator (VA = 6)
   |   |   |   |   |  Evaluate Ungrouped ANY AGGREGATE.
   |   |   |   |   |  Scanning only up to the first qualifying row.
   |   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |   |RESTRICT Operator (VA = 5)(9)(0)(0)(15)(0)
   |   |   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 4)
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  tb_jpachi_filesprocess
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  Table Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning at start of table.
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |  END OF QUERY PLAN FOR SUBQUERY 1.
```

Comment: You don't provide any information regarding the query plan or schema layout but as a starting point the join with the mass of substrings and other functions within it is almost certainly causing poor join criteria and ignoring indexes which will lead to very poor performance.

You don't mention which Sybase product you're using (ASE, IQ etc) so hard to confirm which options you have available for tuning.

If you have an option to change the schema you really should store the filename in a column if you want to join on it regularly. Post the showplan for the query for better help.

Comment: @ Rich Campbell i am using ASE and plan i will post it

Comment: @ Rich Campbell Updated the query plan.

Comment: As I suspected it's tablescanning the  tb_jpachi_cycle table. Then for every row in that table it's tablescanning the tb_jpachi_filesprocess table one by one in your sub-query which will be massively slow. This is very likely due to the way you're concatenating your columns together for the join so see if there's another way to do the join or you you may need additional indexes to speed it up. A 'not in' clause is inefficient - imagine saying 'Which names are in a telephone directory which are not 'Jones' for example it has to search the whole book = inefficient. Look to match instead.